# Maximal dot project with a non increasing vector

Tags: optimization, proof-writing, vectors

Say $\mathbf{a}$ is a vector of non-increasing elements

i.e. $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ s.t $a_i\geq a_j\iff i<j$

Now given another vector $\mathbf{o}=(1,1/2,1/3,\ldots,1/n)^\top$, i'd like to prove that $\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{o}\geq \mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{o}'$ where $\mathbf{o}'$ is any permutation of $\mathbf{o}$.

This seems like it should be very obviously true but I'm struggling to come up with concrete proof since it's difficult to reason about spaces of permutations.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$S_1 = \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{o} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{a_k}{k} $

And let the second sum be with $i,j$ entries permutated, then

$S_2 = \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{o'} = \left(S_1 - \dfrac{a_i}{i} - \dfrac{a_j}{j} \right) + \dfrac{a_i}{j} + \dfrac{a_j}{i} $

Taking the difference,

$S_2 - S_1 = \left(\dfrac{1}{i} - \dfrac{1}{j} \right) \left( a_j - a_i \right) $

Now, we can assume that $ i \lt j $ , then $ a_j - a_i \le 0 $ and $ \dfrac{1}{i} - \dfrac{1}{j} \gt 0 $

Hence $S_2 - S1 \le 0 $

Thus $ \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{o'} \le \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{o} $

Comment: Does proving that $\mathbf{o}'$ with two entries permuted generalize to proving this for any $\mathbf{o}'$?

Comment: Yes, because any permutation $\mathbf{o'}$ is a sequence of single permutations between two entries.

Comment: But can you prove that every two entry permutation in the sequence from $o\to o'$ satisfies $i<j$. For example $(a,b,c)\to(c,a,b)$ can be expressed as $(a,b,c)\to (c,b,a)\to (c,a,b)$ where the last swap with $b,a$ does not satisfy the property

Comment: The general question is can you make any permutation starting from a non-increasing sequence that only do pairwise swaps of elements where the first element is still $\geq$ then the second?

Comment: The same result is obtained if we assume that $i \gt j $.